# OnClick function is not working in Safari browser but the code is working fine on other browsers. What could be potential issue?

Tags: reactjs, macos, safari

I tested it on Chrome and Firefox it is working well over there but on safari onClick is not working.

```
function someComp=()=>{
const [isDisabled,setIsDisabled]=useState(false);
const [Input,setInput]=useState("");
return(
   <div>
    <input value={Input} onChange={(e)=>setInput(e.target.value)} disabled={isDisabled}/>
    <img src="/image" role="presentation" onClick={()=>setIsDisabled(!isDisabled)}/>
   </div>)
}
```

Above code working fine in other browsers but not working in safari.

Comment: Can't reproduce this locally but it's a bit odd to be specifying `role="presentation"` for an element (i.e. [marking it as decorative](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/decorative/)) when it has associated functionality ... Does removing the `role` (and introducing a non-empty `alt`) restore the functionality for Safari?