# Form submit and onclick() behaviour of Safari (desktop)

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I am aware there are quite a few threads on this, yet none of these solutions explains why, nor did any work for me (see below, if this is a duplicate to a thread with a solution, please do show me the way!).

I have a form triggering a post request and via onclick() it should show a loading spinner while this request is processing. That loading spinner does sometimes (randomly) not get displayed in Safari (desktop). The code works fine in Chrome and Firefox. I assume the form gets submitted before the js can update, but this is just a guess. I tried using onfocus() (onsubmit/on…whatever) instead, but to no avail. Also it does not help if i use an event handler instead of onclick(), same random results. Why does this not work in Safari? How can I make this work reliably?

My code is the simplest one imaginable, the form:

```
    <form action="/myform" method="post">
      <input
        type="submit"
        id="stage1button"
        name="myformname"
        value="Click me"
        onclick="javascript:stage2loading();"
      />
    </form>
```

And the javascript function triggered:

```
function stage2loading() {
  document.getElementById("stage2circle").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("stage2loader").style.display = "block";
}
```

Similar threads – none of them actually explain what happens though:

[Safari ignores submit alterations in onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040110/safari-ignores-submit-alterations-in-onclick-event?rq=2)

[OnClick not working on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40279820/onclick-not-working-on-safari)

[OnClick function is not working in Safari browser but the code is working fine on other browsers. What could be potential issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76254009/onclick-function-is-not-working-in-safari-browser-but-the-code-is-working-fine-o)

[onclick event in select HTML not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769374/onclick-event-in-select-html-not-working-in-safari)

Answer (score 0):

For those running into the same problem, this is not really an explanation, but a workaround. What works is submitting the form from js with a delay, so the page has some time to update - that seems to work reliably:

```
<button onclick="javascript:stage2loading();">Click me</button>
<form id="stage1form" action="/myform" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="myformname" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and then in js:

```
function stage2loading() {
  document.getElementById("stage2circle").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("stage2loader").style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById("stage1form").submit();
  }, 500); // workaround for safari onclick-bug, give the spinner time to load
}
```